# Getting tokens based on length and position inside input

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, jison

On my input I have stream of characters which are not separated by any delimiter, like this:

```
input = "150001"
```

I want to make parser(using JISON), which tokenize based on position and length, this should be my tokens:

```
15 - system id (first 2 numbers)
0001 - order num (4 numbers after)
```

Can you give me some advice how can I accomplish this,
I tried to add my tokens like this:

```
    %lex
    %%

     [0-9]{2}    return "SYSTEM_ID"
     [0-9]{4}    return "ORDER_NUM"

   \lex
   %%
```

But as expected this is not working :)

Is there some way to parse this kind of inputs, where you parse by length of characters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple parser using state-declarations, and assigning a state to each of those rules.  Referring to JISON's [documentation](http://zaach.github.io/jison/docs/#lexical-analysis), it would change to something like this (noting that your lexer is still incomplete because it does nothing for the identifier or "="):

```
%lex 
%s system_id order_num
%%
 /* some more logic is needed to accept identifier, then "=", each
    with its own state, and beginning "system_id" state.
  */
 <system_id>[0-9]{2}    this.begin("order_num"); return "SYSTEM_ID"
 <order_num>[0-9]{4}    this.begin('INITIAL'); return "ORDER_NUM"
```

\lex
   %%